# Monit - issue to run program that displays image

Tags: monitoring

I'm working on a Windows 7 machine, having a VM for Ubuntu (image disk: 12.04-desktop-i386.iso).

On the VM I installed Monit 5.3.2, and configured some processes and applications.
So I created a script to run my application. This application should display some content on the screen (Im basically displaying two images, using Feh).

The thing is: if I call my script through the command line, it runs ok, and display the images.
But if I run through monit, it seems to be running ok, but it doesn't display the images.In the case I try to debug it (remote debug), then I can see the images. So I was supposing this could be some kind of configuration, but didn't find out what (even using the option -I wou'ldn't work).

I"m showing below more details:

-Piece of script on Monit----

```
check program runMediaHandler with path "/usr/bin/runMediaHandler.sh"
 if status == 1 then alert
```

-runMediaHandler.sh ----

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /home/thais/Desktop/MediaHandler_RC2.jar
```

Summarizing:

1.What works:

- if I run java directly: java -jar /home/thais/Desktop/MediaHandler_RC2.jar
- if I run the script directly: runMediaHandler.sh
- if I remote debug putting a breakpoint where the image should be displayed

2.What does not work:

- putting that piece of information on Monit to "check program", writen above (even if calling monit -I start runMediaHandler)

I'm strongly believing it's related to some background issue, otherwise, why it would display the picture using remote debug?

Thank you in advance,

Thaís

Answer (score 1):

I'm just posting how I did to solve it in case someday someone needs a similar help...

In the end I tried a few steps that made my program work

1. Not sure if necessary, but I executed the command line (according to monit manual) to make monit run on the foreground:

   ```
   /usr/bin/monit -Ic /etc/monit/monitrc
   ```
2. I changed my script to set a display and to execute with my user. See how it's now:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash    
   export DISPLAY=:0.0
   su -c "java -jar /home/thais/Desktop/MediaHandler_RC2.jar" thais
   ```